# Reshaping a numpy array into desired shape

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, reshape, numpy-ndarray

I am working in numpy and have a numpy array of the form;

```
[[ 1,  2,  3],
 [ 4,  5,  6],
 [ 7,  8,  9],
 [10, 11, 12],
 [13, 14, 15],
 [16, 17, 18],
 [19, 20, 21],
 [22, 23, 24]]
```

I want to use only the reshape and transpose functions and obtain the following array:

```
[[ 1,  2,  3,  7,  8,  9, 13, 14, 15, 19, 20, 21],
 [ 4,  5,  6, 10, 11, 12, 16, 17, 18, 22, 23, 24]]
```

Can this be done? I have spent hours trying and am starting to think it just can't be done - am I missing something obvious?

Comment: `a.reshape(2,-1]`?

Comment: This does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reshape into columns, then transpose, then reshape with something like:

```
a = np.array([[ 1,2,3],
 [ 4,5,6],
 [ 7,8,9],
 [10, 11, 12],
 [13, 14, 15],
 [16, 17, 18],
 [19, 20, 21],
 [22, 23, 24]])

a.reshape(-1, 2, 3).transpose((1, 0, 2)).reshape(2, -1)

# array([[ 1,  2,  3,  7,  8,  9, 13, 14, 15, 19, 20, 21],
#        [ 4,  5,  6, 10, 11, 12, 16, 17, 18, 22, 23, 24]])
```

Comment: I am a bit confused... why was a 3rd dimension added? can this be done without 3 dimensions?

Comment: @JDoe2 maybe…but I don't know how to separate the even and odd rows using only reshape and transpose without adding another column.

Comment: Expanding the number of blocks is the usual first step.  Both the source and result contain 4 blocks of size (2,3), just in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to slice `odd` and `even` and pass them to `np.reshape`.

```
a_out = np.reshape([a[::2], a[1::2]], (2,-1))

Out[81]:
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  7,  8,  9, 13, 14, 15, 19, 20, 21],
       [ 4,  5,  6, 10, 11, 12, 16, 17, 18, 22, 23, 24]])
```